# Code including <fstream> does not compile

Tags: c++, fstream

I found the following bit of code on here and was trying to compile it in order to learn some programming:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    // Which disk?
    char diskName[] = "/dev/sda";
    std::string diskError = std::string() + diskName + ": ";

    // Open device file
    std::ifstream disk(diskName, std::ios_base::binary);

    if(!disk)
        throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));

    // Seek to 54321'th sector
    disk.seekg(512 * 54321);
    if(!disk)
        throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));

    // Read in one sector
    std::vector<char> buffer(512);
    disk.read(&buffer[0], 512);
    if(!disk)
        throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));
}
```

The compiler is complaining on the line that reads:

```
#include <fstream>
```

The error message is:

'fstream' file not found

Is there some library I need to download?

Answer (score 4):

You compiled it with `gcc` (the C front-end) instead of `g++` (the C++ front-end).

`<fstream>` does not exist in C.

Oops!

Comment: Ok, so how do I tell Xcode to use g++ ?

Comment: I figured it out.  For file type over on the right side of the Xcode window when main.c is selected, I changed it to C++ source and it got past the error.

Comment: @user1573041 C++ source files should be named `.cpp` and **not** `.c`. Use this convention else everybody trying to compile your code will have a hard time figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: Agreed and thank you.  I just blew away the project and started another as C++.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  For file type over on the right side of the Xcode window when main.c is selected, I changed it to C++ source and it got past the error.

Comment: it'd be better rename the file to main.cpp like H2CO3 said, else this will be hard to figure out for anyone else